# Clean URLs to my Drupal & site

Tags: url, drupal-7, clean-urls

I am new to Drupal &, I went through drupal guides for enabling clean urls, but at some point getting stuck. How to enable clean URLs in my Drupal 7 site?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, try enabling "rewrite" module for apache,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After that You need to replace the occurrence of **AllowOverride none** to **AllowOverride all** in your site-available file

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

And finally you need to enable clean-url form your drupal site.

```
Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata 

 OR navigate to

http://[your-site]/admin/config/search/clean-urls
```

Comment: @ Shrish, Thank You for your answer. I have acheived clean url for my site & the URL looks like the :-http://localhost/drupaltest2/about , now i want the URL as http://localhost/drupaltest2/10001. How can i achieve this? Please guide me.

Comment: Navigare to this on your drupal installation and create one alias for you link,

Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » URL aliases

or goto this url 

[site-name]/admin/config/search/path/add

Comment: Are there any Path Auto Menu Patterns to achieve the URL as per my requirement

Comment: PathAuto module creates a automatic alias for you.

https://drupal.org/project/pathauto

Comment: Yes I have got the path for my site as localhost/mysite/about, but i want to have localhost/mysite/10001. Where the [node:title] should be replaced by number. Please help me in getting this.

Comment: instruction not clear .. are telling to put node id on node link ?

Comment: Ya something like that. I am trying to put [node:id] in place of [node:title} but its not working>.